# Unable to Drag to rearrange layer drawing order in Table of Contents of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, windows-7

I'm new to working in ArcMap, but I seem to have a very small issue.

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2 on Windows 7 Ultimate and for some reason, I can't rearrange the layers I'm working with in the table of contents by clicking and dragging them in the order I want.

Is there some sort of option I have to enable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should check that you are using the List By Drawing Order view of your Table of Contents.

Of the four views described in [Using the table of contents](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//006600000006000000) it is the only one which will allow you to change the drawing order.